# Case Sensitive Commands in Bash Shell

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to understand how Bash executes commands. When I run `cal`, I see this:

```
   December 2021      
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
          1  2  3  4  
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11  
12 13 14 15 16 17 18  
19 20 21 22 23 24 25  
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

However, when I run `CAL`, I see this:

```
    December 2021     
Mo     6 13 20 27   
Tu     7 14 21 28   
We  1  8 15 22 29   
Th  2  9 16 23 30   
Fr  3 10 17 24 31   
Sa  4 11 18 25      
Su  5 12 19 26
```

As the results are slightly different, I assumed that two separate programs were running. When I run `which cal`, I see `/usr/bin/cal`. When I run `which CAL`, I see `/usr/bin/CAL`. However, when I run `ls -l /usr/bin` I do *not* see an entry for `CAL` listed.

What is `CAL`? Is it a program? Is it an alias to another program? Where is it defined?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of running `alias`?

Comment: @DavidPostill when I run `alias`, I see: `run-help=man
which-command=whence`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce most of this behaviour with the `ncal` variant of `cal` installed:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/*cal
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4 May  4  2018 /usr/bin/cal -> ncal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29848 May  4  2018 /usr/bin/ncal
```

The documentation can be found with `man cal` (or `man ncal`) and the interesting part is under the DESCRIPTION where it writes,

> The `cal` utility displays a simple calendar in traditional format and `ncal` offers an alternative layout, more options and the date of Easter

Since `cal` and `ncal` are actually the same program, it follows that the application must check the name by which it's called to determine the output layout. Further investigation determines that a name starting with `cal` is the exception, and calling the program by other names such as `ncal` or `CAL` produce the "new" output with days of the week running vertically downwards:

```
cal     # or any word starting "cal" such as calendar

   December 2021
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31

ncal    # or CAL

    December 2021
Mo     6 13 20 27
Tu     7 14 21 28
We  1  8 15 22 29
Th  2  9 16 23 30
Fr  3 10 17 24 31
Sa  4 11 18 25
Su  5 12 19 26
```

Now, as to why you can't see `CAL`. My *guess* is that you are using a case-insensitive filesystem (perhaps NTFS or vFAT). Such filesystems will find a match to an file regardless of the case, but will also prefer the case of the filename actually stored. Here, that's `cal`. So although `ls /usr/bin/CAL` or `which CAL` will match and return an apparent match to `/usr/bin/CAL`, as the file is actually called `/usr/bin/cal` that's what the default `ls /usr/bin` will list.

Comment: Great answer. Just for fun run this to get a historical perspective: `ncal -p`